# Cannot get GNOME CLASSIC on Ubuntu 18.04 any more!

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-classic

I have set up Ubuntu 18.04 few month ago, and set up there Gnome Classic. It works more or less good (some changes since Ubuntu 16.04 but I was able to set everything up)

Today I installed same Ubuntu 18.04 but Gnome seems behaves differently and I was not able to setup Gnome Classic at all.

It could sound like funny thing but it is not as I have about 10 workstations and it is hard to switch from one to other different user interface. Also I cannot use any animations as often work behind VNC - so I need the classic desktop without those cute color schemes when nautilus shortcut is blue and nautilus itself is brown etc. (How could human do this?)

**How can I setup Gnome classic on Ubuntu 18.04 ? Please help!**

Google indexes a lot of irrelevant articles about whatever Gnome: vanilla, flashback etc but this is not what I need. I need Gnome classic! To clarify here I attach Gnome classic I am looking for, and other gnome. The second one I was able to install today but it is not what I need. Also this flashback seems broken at all, as you can see it not contain favorites folder in Applications menu. Also I cannot get to dash with super(windows) key as I was able in gnome classic.

[image: Gnome classic login]
[image: Gnome classic applications menu]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is gnome-classic and gnome-panel or fallback. Ubuntu GNOME offers a Classic session but it's not at all easily customized and runs on top of the mutter window manager which is much more resource hungry than either MATE's Marco WM or Flashbacks Metacity WM. Or, if you're running either Ubuntu or Ubuntu GNOME you can install 'gnome-panel' which will provide GNOME Flashback session(s). The Flashback w/Metacity session is fairly comparable to MATE w/Marco in resource usage.

Comment: Gnome flashback seems I can easily get, but I not need it - see my post. Am I understand you right - gnome classic takes more resources then others?

Comment: As I understand it, class is more resource hungry.

Comment: got it. I installed mate and playing with it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get gnome classic with

```
sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop
```

What is still curious why it named **classic** on login, but packet contains **vanilla** instead.

I also tried Mate and it seems good, but I feel better with gnome classic.