# After updating softwares from software center of ubuntu 20.04, there are two version of certain updated software,one of them work but not other one

Tags: 20.04, updates, software-center, snap

From software center of ubuntu 20.04 , I updated some softwares .
But after update , there appeared two verison of Characters,Logs and System Monitor in "Show Applications"
But only updated version of them work and older version only appears but after clicking them nothing happens.And older verison does appear in software center's installed region.
I have Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. This is  [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZVzx.jpg).
And i am first time using a linux distro.
My question is how to remove older version double software from appearing in Software OverviewEdit: 
This is an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04.6 to Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: Did you (1) added a PPA (maybe to install some other software) and/or (2) installed another desktop environment?

Comment: @ChanganAuto no and i dont know what they are

Comment: Do you remember using a command including `add-apt-repository`? If so, which one? You can open Software & Updates > Other software. Is there any lines besides "partners"?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Can please see this link https://imgur.com/qjlevzP

Comment: First of all, this is an upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04. You should've mentioned that. Simply installing normal updates wouldn't have added the duplicates but release upgrading could, depending on the what it was upgraded from. This is why I asked the questions above.Now, while not exactly solving your issue but a start, you can remove everything not ticked in the Other Software tab.

Comment: And, again, did you remember installing an additional desktop environment while using 18.04? You can easily check which ones are available by clicking the cogwheel in the login screen.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Sorry for not mentioning the upgrade. And i removed everything other than ticked ones in Other Softwares Tab. And Desktop Environent seen in login screen are Gnome Classic,Ubuntu and Ubuntu on Wayland

Comment: Possibly snap and deb versions?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Not likely because almost always the icons look the same.

Comment: "Gnome Classic" explains it. Probably you did something like this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079032/cannot-get-gnome-classic-on-ubuntu-18-04-any-more while it was 18.04.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I ran `snap list --all`, which list those doubles and under doubles software ,it was mentioned they were disabled .So i ran          `LANG=C snap list --all | while read snapname ver rev trk pub notes; do if [[ $notes = *disabled* ]]; then sudo snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$rev"; fi; done`        Then i again ran snap list --all .Then those software doubles were not appearing in list in terminal.But they are still present Software Overview.And i tried rebooting

Comment: The duplicates came with "Gnome Classic" and yes, the release upgrade may have added snaps on top of that. The point being this happened because at some point you installed an additional DE. Now, as usual, DEs are easy to add but almost impossible to remove (in this case it was - probably - installed using the metapackage mentioned in the answer linked above; a metapackage does nothing by itself so removing it won't remove anything else it installed).

Comment: @ChanganAuto so any fix?

Comment: No, not really. Do your backups and install fresh (and don't add additional DEs unless you're prepared to deal with the consequences).

Comment: Hello, So what did you and changanauto concluded of? Did you guys found a fix ?

Comment: @Someone i unistalled ubuntu and am now using debian with gnome

Comment: @Subham o.O Debian? Why not Ubuntu? You know your questions are now off-topic here.